# Class App\Http\Controllers\v1\Random\UserController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to get a controller in the following folder: `app/Http/Controllers/v1/Random/UserController.php` but I'm getting the error: `Class App\Http\Controllers\v1\Random\UserController does not exist`

**api.php**

```
// App v1 API
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
    require base_path('routes/api/v1.php');
});
```

**routes/api/v1.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'random', 'namespace' => 'v1\Random'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function (){
        Route::get('', 'UserController@index');
    });
});
```

[image: folder structure]

**UserController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class UserController extends Controller{...}
```

I have tried altering the name space at `v1.php` to  `App\Http\Controllers\v1\Random` but it gives the same error duplicating the `App\Http\Controllers\v1\Random`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the namespace of your controller to `App\Http\Controllers\v1\Random`.

**UserController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\v1\Random;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
// ...

class UserController extends Controller{...}
```

**api.php**

```
// App v1 API
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
    require base_path('routes/api/v1.php');
});
```

**routes/api/v1.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'random', 'namespace' => 'v1\Random'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function (){
        Route::get('', 'UserController@index');
    });
});
```